# Error Thrown When Toggling 'Quick Edit' on a List or Library

Tags: error, debugging, quick-edit, error-handling

For some reason users are getting the following popup/error when toggling 'Quick Edit' on a list or library.

> This site says...
>
> Assertion Failed: Edit manager is still in Editing state, but focus is on the grid's input element!
>
> Break into debugger?

[image: Popup Error]

No errors are showing in Chrome's developer tools console. However it is showing the following messages... (I'm not sure if they are related.)

```
[Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a 'DOMSubtreeModified' event. Consider using MutationObserver to make the page more responsive.
```

```
[Violation] 'click' handler took 34811ms
```

```
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 35ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 38ms
```

We are running SharePoint 2013

Comment: I noticed the same thing on a 2016 on-prem install the day before... Which SharePoint version are you on?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in 2016, after a taxonomy-column was added to the list. It does not occur in 2013 or online, though.

Comment: I've added the answer to your question as an edit. Thanks for your interest :)